# UIWebView and page-break-* css doesn't work with Airprint

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, airprint

I would like to print an html page with this css file

```
@media print {
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Any tricks?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `display: block;`

```
@media print {
    table { display: block; page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { display: block; page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display: block; display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display: block; display:table-footer-group }
}
```